# How to limit concurrent http requests with Mono & Flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to handle `Flux` to limit concurrent HTTP requests made by List of `Mono`.

When some requests are done (received responses), then service requests another until the total count of waiting requests is 15.

A single request returns a list and triggers another request depending on the result.

At this point, I want to send requests with limited concurrency.
Because consumer side, too many HTTP requests make an opposite server in trouble.

I used `flatMapMany` like below.

```
public Flux<JsonNode> syncData() {
    return service1
        .getData(param1)
        .flatMapMany(res -> {
                List<Mono<JsonNode>> totalTask = new ArrayList<>();
                Map<String, Object> originData = service2.getDataFromDB(param2);
                res.withArray("data").forEach(row -> {
                       String id = row.get("id").asText();
                       if (originData.containsKey(id)) {
                           totalTask.add(service1.updateRequest(param3));
                       } else {
                            totalTask.add(service1.deleteRequest(param4));
                       }
                       originData.remove(id);
                });
                for (left) {
                    totalTask.add(service1.createRequest(param5));
                }
                return Flux.merge(totalTask);
        });
}
```

```
void syncData() {
    syncDataService.syncData().????;
}
```

I tried chaining `.window(15)`, but it doesn't work. All the requests are sent simultaneously.

How can I handle `Flux` for my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid Project Reactor doesn't provide any implementation of either rate or time limit.

However, you can find a bunch of 3rd party libraries that provide such functionality and are compatible with Project Reactor. As far as I know, [resilience4-reactor](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples-1#decorate-mono-or-flux-with-a-ratelimiter) supports that and is also compatible with Spring and Spring Boot frameworks.

> The `RateLimiterOperator` checks if a downstream subscriber/observer can acquire a permission to subscribe to an upstream Publisher. If the rate limit would be exceeded, the `RateLimiterOperator` could either delay requesting data from the upstream or it can emit a `RequestNotPermitted` error to the downstream subscriber.

```
RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.ofDefaults("name");
Mono.fromCallable(backendService::doSomething)
    .transformDeferred(RateLimiterOperator.of(rateLimiter))
```

More about RateLimiter module itself here: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limitRate` on a Flux. you need to probably reformat your code a bit but see docs here: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#limitRate-int-

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` takes a `concurrency` parameter: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-

```java
Mono<User> getById(int userId) { ... }

Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4).flatMap(client::getById, 2)
```

will limit the number of concurrent requests to 2.